# What is the shape/structure of H2O autoencoder with N hidden layers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o, autoencoder

I'm trying to understand what the H2O autoencoder layer architecture looks like in the case of even and odd numbers of layers. Let's take some concrete examples:

1. Suppose an H2O autoencoder model has 4 hidden layers, 10 neurons per layer ([10, 10, 10, 10]). How many layers would the decoder and encoder have, respectively? Does this mean that the encoder has 1 input layer and 2 hidden layers and decoder has 2 hidden and 1 output?
2. Suppose an H2O autoencoder model has 3 hidden layers, 10 neurons per layer ([10, 10, 10]). How many layers would the encoder and decoder have, respectively?